# Open Microsoft Publisher Document on Linux

Tags: linux, conversion, microsoft-publisher

I'm pretty sure the options consist of

1. Just don't do it (use a nice open standard file format). Not great when someone sends you something.
2. Translate the format on Windows. I think you need Publisher, the viewer won't even print. But you can download a trial version for a once off (been there, done that).
3. Submit the file for online translation to PDF. [www.pdfonline.com/convert-pdf/](http://www.pdfonline.com/convert-pdf/)
4. Use a Windows VM, wine, crossover office, Win4Lin, or otherwise run Publisher "under" linux.

What I really want to do is convert it to something nicer natively under Linux.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Libreoffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/) does support opening publisher files.

Answer (score 4):

I've just used [Zamzar](http://www.zamzar.com/) to do this.  Its a free online service and took about 10 minutes.

It did mess up the format somewhat, but I got all the text, graphics and clip art, which I can now use in Scribus, or tidy up in LibreOffice Writer.

Answer (score 2):

Such a tool appears to not exist - the search I did only came back with the following [article](http://www.brighthub.com/computing/windows-platform/articles/52304.aspx):

> **Why Can't I View .PUB Files?**
> It’s one of the great mysteries of the world – why don’t Microsoft provide a free viewer for Microsoft Publisher (.pub) files?
> As yet, it hasn’t been explained and there doesn’t seem to be anyone presenting a third party alternative. The result of this of course is that anyone wishing to view a Microsoft Publisher document must do so on a PC with the application installed on it, or else view a printed copy of the document!
>
> Read more: http://www.brighthub.com/computing/windows-platform/articles/52304.aspx#ixzz0V75pJTkg

Comment: I got the same impression. One can always hope though.

Comment: Not true, LibreOffice does open them.

Comment: @Leandro - then add a new answer, if the correct one I gave 11 years is no longer correct :)

Comment: Someone already did, and I voted up their answer.

Answer (score 1):

OODraw and Scribus are both excellent Linux publisher alternatives i would recommend, though i think exporting a Publisher file to either of these programs would be harder to do