# Is there a way to extract/export images from Publisher files without having Publisher?

Tags: extract, microsoft-publisher

A client gave me a Publisher file with images in it that I'm supposed to extract out of the file and use for another project. I use OpenOffice and it does not appear to support .pub files.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An older plugin that works with OpenOffice 2.3:

> http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/project/pubooo

I didn't come across anything for the newer 3.x version of OpenOffice.

Comment: **@Force_Flow:** Ended up downloading a trial version of Office 2010, which was crazy slow... funny thing was that when I finally got the files open, that were flat files... :-) ...thanks for the pointer though, I really was unable to find anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

If you could ask your client to use the Pack and Go wizard, the fonts and pictures will be supplied in separate folders that you could then use.  Google the wizard on how to use it.

Comment: I wasn't able to extract images with Office 365 Publisher Pack and Go functionality

Answer (score 0):

I use [File Juicer](http://echoone.com/filejuicer/) to extract images and text out of MS Publisher files. Depending on what is in your Publisher files, it may be the solution you are looking for.

Comment: [Relevant section of the website](http://echoone.com/filejuicer/formats/formats?f=pub).

Answer (score 0):

See also my similar question - [Open Microsoft Publisher Document on Linux](https://superuser.com/q/60685/4060)

In particular, you could try one of the online convert-to-pdf sites (I've used Submit the file for online translation to PDF. www.pdfonline.com/convert-pdf/ before), and then extract what you want from the pdf.

Comment: Maybe, though my experience is that doing that may result in the image files embedded in the file to be reformatted in the process; meaning that colors, resolution, file-format, etc. might be lost. The idea is to extract them as is for the source file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like LibreOffice can open the .pub files.

Answer (score 0):

I extracted images from a .pub file with Office 365 Publisher using

File => Export => Publish HTML (select Web Page HTML)

[image]

All images appear in a separate folder. Though the quality of images is minimal, and any improvement in it appreciated